# Columns not being set to not null in rails 4.2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I must be doing this wrong, but I don't know how:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email null: false
      t.string :user_name null: false
      t.string :first_name null: false
      t.string :last_name null: false
      t.string :auth_token null: false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

When I run: `bin/rake db:reset && bin/rake db:migrate && bin/rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=test`

and inspect the table I see:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  email character varying,
  user_name character varying,
  first_name character varying,
  last_name character varying,
  auth_token character varying,
  created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

The schema also shows:

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "user_name"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "auth_token"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

I have even tried dropping the database and re running the migrations - nothing. **What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: I really have no idea why it didn;t raise an exception, but you are missing comas after names of the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had forgot a commas:

```
create_table :users do |t|
  t.string :email, null: false
  t.string :user_name, null: false
  t.string :first_name, null: false
  t.string :last_name, null: false
  t.string :auth_token, null: false

  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

**EDIT**

My inattention, I hadn't been noticing your sentence after first piece of code. You're wrong when using rake tasks.
You need use

```
rake db:migrate:reset
```

instead of

```
rake db:reset && rake db:migrate
```

- **db:reset** runs db:drop, db:schema:load, db:seed
- **db:migrate:reset** runs db:drop, db:create, db:migrate

Comment: I have also tried with commas and yet o get the same results.

Comment: You need create a new migration because already ran migrations are not running anew.

Comment: Accept that when I drop the database and recreate it commas or no the fields are not marked as not null.

Comment: It's weird without commas there had to be thrown an error.. Is there any info after `rake db:migrate` command?

Comment: Nope the databases get reset and he migrations all run as normal.

Comment: if there no any info then migrations are not running. For instance after creating table must be following output: == 20151018233323 CreateElements: migrating ===================================
-- create_table(:elements)
   -> 0.0153s
== 20151018233323 CreateElements: migrated (0.0155s) ==========================

Comment: This is what I meant by the migrations run as normal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92673/discussion-between-devor-and-kyle-adams).